# Objective C Array completionHandler used in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a completion handler in a framework written in Objective C...

This is a typedef for a block type. It takes an array of PHErrors.

```
typedef void (^PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler)(NSArray *errors);
```

When I try to use this in Swift, I'm doing....

```
 anObject.aMethod(completionHandler: { (errors: [ AnyObject?]) -> () in

 ...rest of code
 }
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '([AnyObject?]) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler!'

Can anyone help, I'm baffled, it looks like it should work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
anObject.aMethod(completionHandler: { (errors: [ AnyObject?]) -> () in 
}
```

should be

```
anObject.aMethod() { errors in 
}
```

In order to dig any deeper, I have to know what `PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler` is

Comment: Thanks your help. The only definition available from the framework I posted in the question, which was typedef void (^PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler)(NSArray *errors);

Comment: There is no need to use either. Closures infer types, so giving it a name is the only requirement like in my example. If you want to be explicit about what type it is, Any will work because I believe all Objects are of type any. NSArray is the official type, and I am unsure of which Arrays are definitively considered to be of type NSArray.

Answer (score 2):

Or better yet, you can still use your `typedef` as `typealias`.

**DEFINE**

```
typealias PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler = (_ errors: [Error]?) -> Void
```

---

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
func myFunctionWithErrorCompletion(completion: PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler) {

    // Define empty array to add errors to
    var errors:[Error]?

    // Do Your Logic that may store errors to array

    // Completion and pass errors
    completion(errors)
}
```

---

**USAGE**

```
func anotherOfMyFunctions() {

    // Call the function
    myFunctionWithErrorCompletion { (errors) in

        if let completionErrors = errors {
            // React to errors
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So my friend solved this problem by simply changing AnyObject to Any

(errors: [Any]?) in

Which baffles me because all objects in an NSArray are objects! So didn't think to try Any.

Im pretty new to Swift mind

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
anObject.aMethod(completionHandler: { (errors:NSArray?) -> () in

 ...rest of code
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that too, but I get...  Cannot convert value of type '(NSArray?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler!'

Comment: what is PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler??? cmd click it and show me the definition.

Comment: also anObject.aMethod(completionHandler: { (errors: [ AnyObject?]) -> () in } should be anObject.aMethod() { errors in }

Comment: cmd click shows no definition. typedef void (^PHBridgeSendErrorArrayCompletionHandler)(NSArray *errors); in the Objective-C header is the only information have to go by.  This problem was resolved by replacing AnyObject with Any. Thanks for your help